# is there a way to have a remote slideshow on Windows?

Tags: pdf, slideshow

I have a PDF slideshow (not PowerPoint), and I want to present the slideshow to someone remotely. I can use Skype for the voice, but I want to also be able to have the slides he sees synchronized with what I see without me having to let him know which slide I am on (so when I click, he goes to the next slide as well). Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) in presentation mode. It will allow you to share your screen without allowing the other person control.

Comment: is there something which is free?

Comment: @remotess TeamViewer is free.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Skype (free version), you can share your screen with one person at a time.

[image]

http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/features/allfeatures/screen-sharing/